# Esri map with flex show name on navigator instead of coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, apache-flex, esri, directions

I am using com.esri.ags.components.directions on esri map and I added the stops by coordinates.
So how can I assign a name to the stop so it will be showing on screen and when printing instead of coordinates?

This is the code I added the stops into

```
        var stop:DirectionsStop = mainUIComponent.myDirections.stopProvider[0];
        stop.editable = false;
        stop.searchTerm = UserSession.getCurrentUserDTO().dealerCoordinatesDTO.AddressLongitude + ","
            + UserSession.getCurrentUserDTO().dealerCoordinatesDTO.AddressLatitude;
        var stopCount:int=1;

        for( var i:int=0; i < customersToVisitsList.length; i++)
        {               
            var point:DealerQuestMapPoint=new DealerQuestMapPoint(
                customersToVisitsList[i].addressLongitude,customersToVisitsList[i].addressLatitude);
            point.pointType="CUSTOMER";
            point.targetObject=customersToVisitsList[i];
            point.address = customersToVisitsList[i].address;
            var imageTooltip:String//="Test";
            customersToVisitsList[i].customerName.toString()
                +"\n"+customersToVisitsList[i].address.toString() 
                +", "+customersToVisitsList[i].city.toString()
                +"\n"+customersToVisitsList[i].state.toString()
                +", "+customersToVisitsList[i].zip.toString();

            renderMapPoint(mainUIComponent.customersLayer,
                point,
                customersToVisitsList[i].customer_id,
                imageTooltip,
                customersToVisitsList[i],
                mainUIComponent.blueSymbol);
            if(i==0)
            {
                var stop1:DirectionsStop = mainUIComponent.myDirections.stopProvider[1];  

                stop1.editable = true;  
                stop1.searchTerm = point.lon.toString() + "," + point.lat.toString();
                stop1.name = customersToVisitsList[i].customerName.toString();

            }
            else
            {
                stopCount+=1;  
                var st:DirectionsStop = new DirectionsStop();  

                st.editable = true;
                st.searchTerm = point.lon.toString() + "," + point.lat.toString();
                st.name = customersToVisitsList[i].customerName.toString();

                mainUIComponent.myDirections.stopProvider.addItem(st); 
            }               
        }

        mainUIComponent.myDirections.getDirections();
```

I checked the documentation and I found nothing to do this because usually they deal with address but dealing with coordinates makes it a must to rename it to another name.

[Screenshot of the map with coordinates written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On4sY.png)

[image]

Comment: Did you check the documentation? Does it say this is possible? Have you tried asking the creators (via forum, via email, etc)? No-one is magic here so if you just give two sentences we cannot help you... Show us some small testable code of your issue, so we see your problem in action.

Comment: I didn't find the code and the documentation is really weak and I didn't find  any thing in it to help me with this situation.
I added the code and a screen shot of the map with coordinates.